# Child window (CEdit) losing focus

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, cedit

I am programming in C++ using MFC Document/View architecture. I have been trying to achieve something similar to [MFC CEdit lose focus handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354475/mfc-cedit-lose-focus-handler). I processed the message EN_KILLFOCUS as the answer suggests.

Basically, I'm doing this: I have text drawn in the view. When the users clicks the area of the text in the view, I position and show the CEdit window on top of it so users are able to edit the text. When the edit loses focus, I get the CEdit text and save it in the document. Then invalidate the view.

However, I seem to only receive the EN_KILLFOCUS message when the view loses focus. I have to click somewhere else, e.g. a docking window, or the toolbar, to make the CEdit lose focus. I want it to happen when I click anywhere else on the view, outside the CEdit box.

I am creating the CEdit with WS_CHILD style. I tried WS_POPUP but still the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a CEdit derived class/control. And create an instance of this class in your View
Handle the EN_KILLFOCUS in the derived class. You will be able to handle this message once user clicks outside the edit control window.

Keep your editbox as WS_CHILD.

Set focus to view on view's mouse down, call SerFocus() on view's LButtonDown.

Comment: Hmm... I tried this. But it doesn't seem to work. Still I only receive the message if the whole view loses focus.

Comment: Hmm..Are you setting focus to your view on view's mouse down? If not, call SerFocus() on view's LButtonDown..

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. However, I find that there is no point in subclassing the CEdit anymore. I can just handle the EN_KILLFOCUS in the parent's window OnCommand

Comment: Can you change your answer to reflect this? I'll give you the accept as answer and upvote.